# How to find files in Linux without absolute address?

Tags: linux, find

I want get all md5 *.conf file in system. When i find all conf file and with loop "For" :

> for file in $ (find .....) do md5sum $file > /home/username/$name.md5
>   done after execute the script error can not find path
>   "/home/username//etc/*.conf.md5"

I hope true explain.

Comment: please migrate to superuser or ubuntu stackexchange.

Comment: `find /path -type f -exec md5dum '{}' > /home/username/confmd5sums.md5 \;` then you have each of the sums (with the associated filename) contained in a single file. Much easier to query/handle. If you want separate files, then run it though `awk` to write the first field to the file in the second field using `sub` to replace the `.conf` with `.md5` as the filename. (e.g. `awk '{sub(/txt$/,"md5",$2); print $1 > $2}' sumfile.md5`)

Answer (score 1):

you could pipe the output of find to some program that strips the standard input for you such as `sed` or `cut`

```sh
find / -name "*.conf" | rev | cut -d "/" -f 1 | rev
```

First we reverse the input so we can use cut to get the 'first' field, then reverse it again so we get the correct order of letters in the output.

or

```sh
find / -name "*.conf" | sed -E "s/.*\/(.*)$/\1/"
```

To get the md5sum of those files just use xargs.
There is no need to cut off the file path for that.

```sh
find / -name "*.conf" | xargs md5sum
```

Answer (score 0):

Error clearly says, path is not available, so you can check the path available or not.
And instead of saving in etc path same in your home path.

find / -name "md5 *.conf"  |  while read line
do
     md5sum "$line" >> /home/user/md5sum.txt
done

Comment: I want per each file founded create a md5 file. not all md5 in text file